# Repeating a series to create a df in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series, `s`

```
       A   
0     1.5         
1     2.5                  
2     1.3
```

How do I repeat this column 9 times to create a dataframe. 
Expected output:

```
      A             A         ...       A
0     1.5          1.5        ...      1.5         
1     2.5          2.5        ...      2.5                 
2     1.3          1.3        ...      1.3
```

`df.shape` is `(3, 9)`

I can use `pd.concat` but this is a bit messy. I tried `np.repeat` but it wouldn't work along `axis=1`, and `axis=0` isn't what I need

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, what you meant by **messy** but `pd.concat`
handles it pretty well here:

```
pd.concat([s for i in range(9)], axis=1)
```

you can pass

```
keys=[f'A{i}' for i in range(9)]
```

to `pd.concat` to make distinct column names.

Comment: Sorry, I was being dim by not using pd.concat properly. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

> **numpy** approach: `numpy.repeat` and `numpy.reshape` with `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array(['1.5','2.5','1.3']) # numpy array

s = pd.Series(data) # pandas series
```

> Option 1, by using the `numpy.ndarray`, `numpy.repeat` and `numpy.reshape`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(data,9).reshape((3, 9)), columns=['A' for i in range(9)])
```

> Option 2, by using the values of the Series (values of a pandas.Series is also numpy.ndarray):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(s.values,9).reshape((3, 9)), columns=['A' for i in range(9)])
```

> Option 3, with different column names:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(s.values,9).reshape((3, 9)), columns=[f'A{i}' for i in range(9)])
```

> `Output`:
>
> Option1:

```
df:
      A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A
0   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
1   2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
2   1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3
```

> Option 2:

```
df1:
      A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A
0   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
1   2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
2   1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3
```

> Option 3:

```
df2:
     A0  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8
0   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
1   2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
2   1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3
```

[numpy.repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat)

[numpy.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and feed to `pd.DataFrame`:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(df.values, (1, 10)),
                   columns=[f'A{i:02d}' for i in range(1, 11)])

print(res)

   A01  A02  A03  A04  A05  A06  A07  A08  A09  A10
0  1.5  1.5  1.5  1.5  1.5  1.5  1.5  1.5  1.5  1.5
1  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5
2  1.3  1.3  1.3  1.3  1.3  1.3  1.3  1.3  1.3  1.3
```

I advise **not** to repeat column names, as this may cause problems in subsequent logic.

Answer (score 0):

The series you mentioned can be created as follows

```
a = Series ({0: 1.5, 1:2.5, 2:1.3}, name='A')
```

To make a `DataFrame` with say 9 repeating columns, the code would be

```
b = DataFrame([a]*9).T
```

The `.T` transforms the `DataFrame` in to the desired shape.

As all column names are same: `A` in this case. You could either explicitly rename the columns with

```
b.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
```

or access the desired column with the `.iloc` indexer as follows.

```
b.iloc[:, 3] = [7.5, 8.5, 9.5]
```

This would replace the 4th column in the `DataFrame`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series ({0: 1.5, 1:2.5, 2:1.3}, name='A')
pd.DataFrame(np.tile(s, (10, 1)).T, columns=[f'A{i}' for i in range(10)])
```

**Output**

```
    A0  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9
0   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
1   2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
2   1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.3
```

Comment: Is this any different to [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52151926/9209546)?